# Chrome opens 'data;' instead of webpage in automation with capybara

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, capybara, appium

I am using `appium_capybara` to automate web application on real android devices. 
I have done all the configurations for Appium Capybara driver. 
However, when I run my cucumber tests, chrome browser gets launched in my android device, but it does not open the url specified, instead it opens a blank page with **data;** in the address bar.

Can anyone please help me get through it?

Comment: This happens when you open chrome using any automation framework.  Once it's open you should run the command to go to the URL.  If you run in debug can you open it?

Comment: Sorry, Didn't get you. 'If you run in debug can you open it?'

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the line where you tell appium/capybara to go to the url then run the test in debug.  When it gets there is chrome already pointed at data;.  If not then you might have a race condition.  If it is at data; what happens when you run the step that tells it to navigate to the url?  Are there any exceptions when you step into the navigation command?  Sometimes cucumber swallows the exceptions.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?